# Bad mod_rewrite or .htaccess Practices?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm just getting into using mod_rewrite and I want to know from the server gurus what gets under their skin about web developers like me playing around with their apaches.  Are there some common developer mistakes and/or bad practices to avoid?

Comment: This sounds like a Server Fault question.

Comment: @Jens I'd never heard of that site!  Very cool.